# Inserting an Office Open XML (OOXML) file into MySQL as a blob

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, blob, openxml

I have a lot of Office Open XML (OOXML) files saved with the extension XML and I'm trying to insert these files into a MySQL database. I can connect okay, and I've been able to insert strings into different databases with the same syntax. But when I try to insert an XML file into a blob field in the database it tells me I have a problem with my syntax. Is there something special I should be doing because of the format of the files?

```
public Insertion(Connection conn) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException{

    System.out.println("Trying to insert Data..");

    String filePath1 = "C:/Users/SAVAGD05/Documents/RMP/Section1.XML";
    InputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath1));
    String filePath2 = "C:/Users/SAVAGD05/Documents/RMP/Section1.XML";
    InputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath2));
    String filePath3 = "C:/Users/SAVAGD05/Documents/RMP/Section1.XML";
    InputStream inputStream3 = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath3));

    System.out.println("It did this part");

    String SQL = "INSERT INTO (1,2,3) values(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);


    statement.setBlob(1, inputStream1);
    statement.setBlob(2, inputStream2);
    statement.setBlob(3, inputStream3);
    statement.executeUpdate();


    System.out.println("Data inserted.");
    conn.close();
    System.out.println("Connection Closed");
    System.out.println("Have a Nice Day and Goodbye.");
    }


}
```

This is the error:

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1,2,3)
>   values(_binary'PK\0\0\0\0\0!\0?RH?\0\0?\0\0\0[Content_Types].'
>   at line 1".

On my console, a few of the 0s come out as a question mark in a box instead.

Comment: What does your table look like and what is you aim? Do you really want to save three blobs into one record or do you want to save each blob into its own record? In each case your query is missing a table name: `INSERT INTO table_name (col_name1, col_name2) VALUES (...), (...);`

Comment: My table has the column names "Section1", "Section2" and "Section3". I've just updated the Syntax to: String SQL = "INSERT INTO (Section1, Section2, Section3) values(?,?,?)"; but this still hasn't changed anything about the error.

Comment: You still have not specified a table name: `String SQL = "INSERT INTO your_table_name_here (Section1, Section2, Section3) values(?,?,?)";`

Comment: I've just done it. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

Okay wow I've realised it was just a small syntax error. 
This:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO (1,2,3) values(?,?,?)";
```

Needed to be:

```
 String SQL = "INSERT INTO sections(idSections,Section1,Section2,Section3) values(?,?,?,?)";
```

as I needed to state the table name as well as give the id field a value.

There isn't a problem with the ooxml data in an xml extension as it turns out since the resulting query can be opened in MS Word (Which is what I aimed for/wanted)